# Django: Insert new row with 'order' value of the next highest value avoiding race condition

Tags: python, mysql, django

Say I have some models:

```
from django.db import models


class List(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)


class ListElement(models.Model):
    lst = models.ForeignKey(List)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    the_order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("lst", "the_order"),)
```

and I want to append a new `ListElement` on to a `List` with the next-highest `the_order` value. How do I do this without creating a race condition whereby another `ListElement` is inserted between looking up the highest `the_order` and inserting new one?

I have looked into [select_for_update()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-for-update) but that won't stop a new INSERT from taking place, just stop the existing elements from being changed. I have also thought about using transactions, but that will simply fail if another thread gets there before us, and I don't want to loop until we succeed.

What I was thinking is along the lines of the following MySQL query

```
INSERT INTO list_elements (name, lists_id, the_order) VALUES ("another element", 1, (SELECT MAX(the_order)+1 FROM list_elements WHERE lists_id = 1));
```

however, even this is invalid SQL since you're not able to SELECT from the table you're INSERTing into.

Perhaps there is a way using [Django's F() expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F), but I haven't been able to get anything working with it.

AUTO_INCREMENT won't help here either since it's table-wide and not per foreign key.

EDIT:
This SQL does seem to do the trick, however, there [doesn't appear to be a way to use the INSERT ... SELECT function from Django's ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14090031/1791183).

```
INSERT INTO list_elements (name, lists_id, the_order) SELECT "another element", 1, MAX(the_order)+1 FROM list_elements WHERE lists_id = 1;
```

Comment: what about overriding `save()` in `ListElement` to set `the_order` to `max(the_order)+1`?

Comment: @SaurabhGoyal The problem is that it's not an atomic operation. You have to first look up the max, then INSERT/UPDATE the instance with the value +1. That's a race condition as another row could have picked that number in  between the operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For concurrency problems in Django & relational databases, you could write table lock to achieve atomic transactions. I came across this problem and found this great code snippet from http://shiningpanda.com/mysql-table-lock-django.html. I'm not sure if copy/pasting his code directly here would be offend anybody, but since SO discourage link-only answers, I will cite it anyway(Thanks to ShiningPanda.com for this):

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import contextlib

from django.db import connection


@contextlib.contextmanager
def acquire_table_lock(read, write):
    '''Acquire read & write locks on tables.

    Usage example:
    from polls.models import Poll, Choice
    with acquire_table_lock(read=[Poll], write=[Choice]):
        pass
    '''
    cursor = lock_table(read, write)
    try:
        yield cursor
    finally:
        unlock_table(cursor)


def lock_table(read, write):
    '''Acquire read & write locks on tables.'''
    # MySQL
    if connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'] == 'django.db.backends.mysql':
        # Get the actual table names
        write_tables = [model._meta.db_table for model in write]
        read_tables = [model._meta.db_table for model in read]
        # Statements
        write_statement = ', '.join(['%s WRITE' % table for table in write_tables])
        read_statement = ', '.join(['%s READ' % table for table in read_tables])
        statement = 'LOCK TABLES %s' % ', '.join([write_statement, read_statement])
        # Acquire the lock
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute(statement)
        return cursor
    # Other databases: not supported
    else:
        raise Exception('This backend is not supported: %s' %
                        connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])


def unlock_table(cursor):
    '''Release all acquired locks.'''
    # MySQL
    if connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'] == 'django.db.backends.mysql':
        cursor.execute("UNLOCK TABLES")
    # Other databases: not supported
    else:
        raise Exception('This backend is not supported: %s' %
                        connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
```

> It works with the models declared in your django application, by
>   simply providing two lists:
>
> the list of models to lock for read purposes, and the list of models
>   to lock for write purposes. For instance, using django tutorial's
>   models, you would just call the context manager like this:

```
with acquire_table_lock(read=[models.Poll], write=[models.Choice]):
    # Do something here
    pass
```

It basically creates a python context manager to wrap your insert your ORM statement and do `LOCK TABLES` `UNLOCK TALBES` upon entering and exiting the context.

Comment: Great, thanks for that. Looks like a nice way to handle table locking in Django. I'll see if we end up with a more portable solution before marking this as the answer.

Comment: Is there a solution without blocking an entire table? But I think it's not possible in this case, right?